# how to properly get or merged objects record into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Code sample A and B were code to achieve the same aim.  It queries an API and returns records into objects  as per

```
Object { title: "Title 1", desc: "description 1" }
Object { title: "Title 2", desc: "description 2" }
Object { title: "Title 3", desc: "description 3" }
```

but i want the result to be return into an array something like

```
[
  { title: "Title 1", desc: "description 1" },
  { title: "Title 2", desc: "description 2" },
  { title: "Title 3", desc: "description 3" }
];
```

Here is the code

**Code A**

```
const { records } = await web5.dwn.records.query({
    message: {
      filter: {
    dataFormat: 'application/json'
      }
    },
  });

console.log("total Saved records", records.length);

// Loop through returned records and print text from each
for (let record of records) {
  const rec = await record.data.json();
  console.log(rec);
  };
```

**Code B**

```
const response = await web5.dwn.records.query({
  message: {
    filter: {
    dataFormat: 'application/json'
    },
  },
});
console.log("total Saved records", response.records.length);

// Loop through returned records and print text from each
response.records.forEach(async record => {
const rec = await record.data.json();
  console.log(rec);
 //return await record.data.json();
});
```

Comment: Based on your examples I'd say: `const result = await Promise.all(records.map(record => record.data.json()))`.

Comment: or just keep pushing to an array in the for loop. Code B wont work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop. felix's solution is better since this doesnt need to be sequential